# How to nest selectors within a class

Tags: css

I want to change the attributes for all items within a particular block item dynamically. I envision the css having a structure as below, but can't figure out the exact syntax to do it. I would change the class id of the block items, ie. cls1 and cls2, dynamically with javascript or similar.

```
.cls1 {x: y=z1; ...
     h1 {}
     p {}
     img {}
     a {} ...
    }
.cls2 {x: y=z2; ...
     h1 {}
     p {}
     img {}
     a {} ...
    }
- - - - - - - - -
<div class="cls1">
    ...
    </div>
```

Comment: What you're looking for is [Sass stylesheets](https://sass-lang.com/), which are compiled before publication.

Comment: You can't. You can use a css compiler like `less` or `sass`

Answer (score 0):

With straight CSS, the syntax would look like this:

```css
.cls1 h1 {
  ...
}

.cls1 p {
  ...
}

.cls1 img {
  ...
}

.cls1 a {
  ...
}

.cls2 h1 {
  ...
}

.cls2 p {
  ...
}

.cls2 img {
  ...
}

.cls2 a {
  ...
}
```

With a CSS pre-compiler like [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/), you can use the syntax that you have in your question.

```css
.cls1 {
  h1 {...}
  p {...}
  img {...}
  a {...}
}

.cls2 {
  h1 {...}
  p {...}
  img {...}
  a {...}
}
```